# The orthogonal complement of $M \subset L^2(0,1)$ is the subspace generated by....

Tags: functional-analysis

The orthogonal complement of $M \subset L^2(0,1)$ is the subspace generated by 1, $e^{2\pi ix}$, and $e^{4\pi ix}$.

By definition the orthogonal complement of a subspace $M \subset H$ is the set ${y \epsilon H: <y,m>=0$ for every $m \epsilon M}$. But how do I find it for this problem?

Comment: How is $M$ defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know theory of Fourier series? Functions $f_k(x) = e^{2 \pi k i x}$ form [orthogonal basis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Hilbert_space_interpretation) of $L^2(0,1)$. From this the answer is straight forward.

Comment: I don't know that Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Did you read the part from wiki "Hilbert space interpretation"? What is not clear?